# Javascript function data outside of a function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to create a simple javascript game and I'm running into a problem accessing a function's data outside of it.

This code works perfectly.

```
window.onload = function() {
var FPS = 30;
var ground = new myObject();
var twoground = new myObject();
setInterval(function() {
  clear();
  draw();
  ground.draw(0, 325);
  twoground.draw(125,325);
  alert(ground.xval);
}, 1000/FPS);
};

function myObject(){ 
this.draw = function drawground(groundx, groundy){
this.xval=groundx+125;
this.yval = groundy;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img=new Image()
img.src="ground.png"
img.onload = function() { 
context.drawImage(img,groundx,groundy)}

}

};
```

The above alerts 125 to the browser every time the interval runs, but that's the only way I can do it, for example if I do the following instead.

```
window.onload = function() {
var FPS = 30;
var ground = new myObject();
var twoground = new myObject();
setInterval(function() {
  clear();
  draw();
  ground.draw(0, 325);
  twoground.draw(125,325);
  myalert();
}, 1000/FPS);
};

 function myalert()
{
 alert(ground.xval);
}

function myObject(){ 
this.draw = function drawground(groundx, groundy){
this.xval=groundx+125;
this.yval = groundy;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img=new Image()
img.src="ground.png"
img.onload = function() { 
context.drawImage(img,groundx,groundy)}

}
```

};

What I would expect is the same thing, as it should be calling myalert, which only displays an alert, in the same interval, but it doesn't. I feel like I'm missing something with the way javascript functions work.

Comment: Is passing the `ground` variable to the `myalert()` function an option? 

You could have:
`myalert(ground);` and 
`myalert(g){ alert(g.xval); }`

Comment: Well in the end I won't be alerting anything, this was just the easiest way to demonstrate the problem I'm having. I'm trying to use the xval variable in a checkcollision function. So, once I'm able to figure out how pass the variable correctly I can move onto implementing that.

Comment: Haha. I figured it wasn't as trivial as that. However, I do believe that the idea still applies. Simply pass the object you wish to evaluate from inside the setInterval within the function, to the "myalert" in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable inside a function using the `var` keyword, the variable is put in the function's local scope. To make it accessible outside the function, you can put it in global scope by omitting the `var` keyword.

However, you may also want to consider refactoring your code to avoid global variables by making them properties of a custom object, or passing them as function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is statically scoped, not dynamically scoped. When you refer to `ground` in the second example you are referring to a global variable by the name of `ground`, not, as in the first example, the local variable `ground`. The function passed to `setInterval()` captures the local variable `ground` from its parent function and it is still in scope when `alert()` is evaluated.